# Find hash attribute value on active record rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am developing the application with Ruby on Rail. As in my current project I have an active record model as an example below :

```
<Site id: 6241, collection_id: 7, name: "ABC", properties: {"31"=>20}>
<Site id: 6242, collection_id: 7, name: "ABC", properties: {"10"=>20}>
<Site id: 6243, collection_id: 7, name: "ABC", properties: {"11"=>30}>
```

However, I want to find the site which has the properties with the key '31' and value 20, but I cannot find the way to compare this hash attribute. So is there any way you could suggest me?

Comment: column type `properties` is `hstore`?

Comment: yes, it is stored as the hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If column type `hstore` and db `postgres` you can search by this query:

```
Site.where("properties @> hstore(?, ?)", 'key', 'value')
```

Comment: I am now working with MYSQL, and I try this command but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Also assuming your column type is an hstore, you can just:

```rb
Site.where(properties: { key: "value" })
```

Answer (score 0):

I also use mysql and this will work:
`Site.where(properties: {"31"=>20}.to_yaml)`